# ksh not evaluating variables read from a file

Tags: shell

Question is how to evaluate the complete $variable read from a file.

I have a program combination of python and ksh shell. 
ksh shell executes a python script which reads xmlfile & returns back a classpath & vairables to export & command to execute.

In my case the xml files looks like the following

```
  1<script>
  2          <scriptPath>/home/opapp/apps/ampFeed</scriptPath>
  3         <JAVA_HOME>/local/opt/sunjava-1.6.0_01/jre</JAVA_HOME>
  4         <classpath>"./properties/prod"</classpath>
  5         <classpath>"lib/activation.jar"</classpath>
  6         <classpath>"lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar"</classpath>
           .......
  40         <executionCmd>"$JAVA_HOME/bin/java"</executionCmd>
  43        <executionCmd>"-Dtarget.db.properties=/home/opapp/apps/ampFeed/properties/pr        od"</executionCmd>
  44         <executionCmd>"-classpath"</executionCmd>
           ..........
   </script>
```

My Shell script is very simple

```
$0 == XMlFile
typeset -x JAVA_HOME=`${HOME}/scripts/readXmlFile.py -s $0 -e "JAVA_HOME"
typeset -x CLASSPATH=`${HOME}/scripts/readXmlFile.py -s $0 -e "CLASSPATH"
EXECUTION_CMD=`${HOME}/scripts/readXmlFile.py -s $0 -e "CLASSPATH"

export JAVA_HOME
export CLASSPATH
print JAVA_HOME=$JAVA_HOME
print CLASSPATH=$CLASSPATH
print EXECUTION_CMD=$EXECUTION_CMD

$EXECUTION_CMD
```

Output is the following :-

```
JAVA_HOME="/local/opt/java7/jre"
CLASSPATH=:"./properties/dev1":"lib/activation.jar":"lib/antlr-2.7.6.jar":"lib/aopalliance.jar"
EXECUTION_CMD="$JAVA_HOME/bin/java" -Dtarget.db.properties=/home/opappqa/apps/Feed/properties/dev1" "-classpath" "$CLASSPATH" "ampFeed.generator.FeedGenerator" "-Xms128M" "-Xmx512M"
line 41: "$JAVA_HOME/bin/java": not found
```

Question is how to evaluate the complete CLASSPATH & JAVA_HOME

Comment: It seems readXmlFile.py is returing the values with `"`. When you try to run it, it attempts to run the executable in quotes. You can either `eval` it, but I'd recommend against it, or you could remove the quotes. Or you can try `${EXECUTION_CMD//\"/}`

Comment: @alvits, ...another approach would be to fix the Python script to emit output that doesn't require `eval`. For instance, if instead of putting things in quotes it emitted NUL-delimited raw values, that would be much easier to work with sanely, and wouldn't break support for content with whitespace or glob characters as simply stripping quotes would.

Answer (score 1):

Use `eval` to treat the string as code:

```
eval "$EXECUTION_CMD"
```

Otherwise, POSIX sh behavior (which ksh follows) runs string-splitting and glob expansion parse phases only, not allowing any portion of the string to be treated as syntax.

That said, see [BashFAQ #50](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050) for information on best practices around programmatically generating code. (Some of the advice there is bash-only, but a great deal of it also applies to ksh).